# Apparently, I've been wrong

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adverbs

Apparently, I may not be using *apparently* correctly!

Here's my question: Can I use *apparently* at the end of a sentence for effect (or affect!):

> I already told you what I was doing for Thanksgiving. You don't ever listen to me, apparently.

Thinking:

> Apparently, you really don't ever listen to me.

Is the first example ungrammatical?

Comment: "You do never listen to me" is apparently at least non-idiomatic, if not actually wrong.

Comment: There's no problem with putting it at the end of a sentence. However, "You do never listen" is a bit unusual. Not wrong - "do" can quite correctly be used to add emphasis - but it would be more typical to omit it. :-)

Comment: "You do never listen to me" is flat-out wrong. No native English speaker would say this.

Comment: Both are fine with me.  Both are pretty snarky!

Comment: I can imagine circumstances under which "You do never listen to me" would be unexceptionable.

Comment: @TonyK A: "Sorry, what was that, dearest?" B: "Oh, Stan! You *do* never listen to me."

Answer (score 4):

No, your apparent advisor has no grasp of English grammar. They have a grasp of what they see most often. So-called 'sentence adverbs' can go before or after the main clauses they comment on:

> Surprisingly, giraffes like reggae.
>
> Giraffes like reggae, surprisingly.

Similarly,

> Apparently, the Original Poster is correct and their critic is wrong.
>
> The Original Poster is correct and their critic is wrong, apparently.

Be of no doubt here. The OP's correctness is not merely apparent.